# How to get Top 50 Sessions from Google Analytics Reporting API v4 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've got an analytics reporting api v4 script in Python which returns to me the sessions for certain landing pages and which city the sessions have come from.

Is there a way to limit this to only the top 50 city locations per landing page for sessions so I don't get returned the city's that are landing on them which have like 1 session for example.

Here is the base code for the analytics request:

```
api_client = google_build(serviceName=api_name, version=api_version, 
http=authorized)
for i in developments:
sample_request = {
      'viewId': '6690350',
      'pageSize': 100000,
      'dateRanges': {
          'startDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 30),'%Y-%m-%d'),
          'endDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d')

      },
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
      'orderBys':
        [
            {'fieldName': 'ga:pagePath', 'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING'},
            {'fieldName': 'ga:sessions', 'sortOrder': 'DESCENDING'}
        ],
      'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:pagePath'},{'name': 'ga:city'},{'name': 'ga:latitude'},{'name': 'ga:longitude'}],
      'dimensionFilterClauses' : [
        {
```

Comment: have you tried adding a filter?  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#metricfilterclause

Comment: I've thought about it but not entirely sure how I would go about doing this for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT -** To get top `x` cities for a particular landing page is not feasible through a single query, you will have to either use Content Grouping feature or process the broader response to achieve this.

**Original response -** 
Added to your code might not be complete, *look at metricFilterClauses section added only*

You can get the top 50 results by using pagination and using  PageSize to restrict the number of rows that you get. Just make sure to use `ordering` to sort before you apply pagination.

You will have to use `batchGet request` to execute this - [link to official guide of batchquest](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet)

```
api_client = google_build(serviceName=api_name, version=api_version, 
http=authorized)
for i in developments:
sample_request = {
      'viewId': '6690350',
      'pageSize': 100000,
      'dateRanges': {
          'startDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 30),'%Y-%m-%d'),
          'endDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d')

      },
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
       #add this metric filter to filter out with session more than 50 
      'metricFilterClauses': [{
          "filters": [{
              "metricName": "ga:sessions",
              "operator": "GREATER_THAN",
              "comparisonValue": "50"
          }]
      }]         
      'orderBys':
        [
            {'fieldName': 'ga:pagePath', 'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING'},
            {'fieldName': 'ga:sessions', 'sortOrder': 'DESCENDING'}
        ],
      'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:pagePath'},{'name': 'ga:city'},{'name': 'ga:latitude'},{'name': 'ga:longitude'}]
       #top 50 results  
      'pageSize': 50
```

You can use [MetricFilterClauses](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#metricfilterclause) to filter out particular metric that you need. You can use [different operators available](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#Operator_1) to you to filter out based on conditions you want to use.

Comment: Hi there, this does something different to what I was hoping. This shows city's which had more than 50 sessions. But I am trying to export the top 50 city's which provided sessions to landing pages.

Comment: edited the answer for PageSize, you can restrict the number of rows to 50 with ordering to get it

Comment: Problem with the edit is that it just chucks out 50 results but I want the top 50 sessions for EACH landing page. Unfortunately this edit limits it to the top 50 sessions overall which just stops at the first landing page

Comment: I think that is not feasible in a single query, this can be achieved through content grouping or run multiple queries or process the total response.